# How to remove rows from a dataframe if condition?

Tags: r

I am trying to achieve this using WHILE, but it's too complex for me,there must be a way using dplyr library.

I have a warehouse with:

```
  product_id amount
1       1001      1
2       4911    100
3       4014     32
```

I am writing a function that will pass product_id and amount, and take the required amount out, and if such product_id does not exist or the amount higher that what available return an error.

So, if I ran the function:

```
remove_warehouse(1001,1)
```

Result should be:

```
  product_id amount
1       4911    100
2       4014     32
```

And if I run eiter:

```
remove_warehouse(240,1)
```

or

```
remove_warehouse(4014,60)
```

I should get a generic error "not enough amount or product not present"

Comment: please provide re producible example using dput()

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

One way of writing the function could be

```
remove_warehouse <- function(df, product_id, amount) {
   id = df$product_id == product_id
   if (any(id))
     amount_base = df$amount[id]
   else
     stop("No id present")
   if (amount > amount_base) 
     stop("No sufficient amount")
   else
     df$amount[id] = df$amount[id] - amount
   df
}

remove_warehouse(df, 4911, 90)

#  product_id amount
#1       1001      1
#2       4911     10
#3       4014     32

remove_warehouse(df, 1234, 12)
#Error in remove_warehouse(df, 1234, 12) : No id present

remove_warehouse(df, 1001, 100)
#Error in remove_warehouse(df, 1001, 100) : No sufficient amount
```

This is assuming you will have only one `product_id` in your `df`.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(product_id = c(1001L, 4911L, 4014L), amount = c(1L, 
100L, 32L)), .Names = c("product_id", "amount"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```